# INSERT only non-existing features into PostgreSQL/PostGIS table with FME

Tags: postgresql, fme-form, insert

I have a PostGIS table of, lets say, adresses, for example

```
id | adr            | geom
----------------------------
1  | Rathausplatz 1 | POINT
2  | Dorfstraße 2   | POINT
3  | Kirchenweg 3   | POINT
```

With FME I would like to insert features to my adresses table but only features that *do not exists* (based on non-equality of attribute `adr`), i.e. for incoming features

```
adr            | geom
----------------------------
Rathausplatz 1 | POINT
Dorfstraße 2   | POINT
Schlossallee 42| POINT
Elisenstraße 8 | POINT
```

only `Schlossallee 42` and `Elisenstraße 8` should be INSERTed, the first two should be rejected.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FeatureMerger should do that job for you. Use the PostGIS table with unique adresses as requestor, the addresses you wish to insert as supplier. Join on the attribute containing the address. The UnusedSupplier port should output the addresses not existing in the DB.  [image]